# Compare current post Category in select menu

Tags: php, select, categories

I have done this many times but not via a form so i am getting a weird issues when trying to assign a "selected"  based on the current post term id...

Maybe the use of `_the_category` and then `get_categories` creates a conflict? Any one has any idea as to why this might happen?

No matter what the selected item is the last one and not the 
Current post (get the post id via an outside form) category

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$postId = $_POST['postid']; // the value is recieved properly
$currentCategory = get_the_category($postId);  // the value is recieved properly
$currentCategoryId = $currentCategory[0]->term_id; // the value is assigned properly

$categories = get_categories('hide_empty=0'); // the value is recieved properly
$optionname = "postcats"; // the value is recieved properly
$emptyvalue = "";

// SELECET DROP DOWN TERMS
echo '<select name="'.$optionname.'" class="clientList"><option selected="'.$selected.'" value="'.$emptyvalue.'">'.__('Choose a category','sagive').'</option>';
foreach($categories as $category){
    // next line seem to not work!
    if($currentCategoryId == $category->term_id) {$selected = 'selected="selected"';}
    echo '<option name="'.$category->term_id.'" value="'.$category->term_id.'" '.$selected.'>'.$category->name.'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
?>
```

**if i try to echo the $currentCategoryId outside the foreach it works

but not inside it.. kinda weird!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG - i falied to clean "$selected" value... hope this helps someone
if you get confused for a moment like i did

```
<?php 
$postId = $_POST['postid']; // the value is recieved properly
$currentCategory = get_the_category($postId);  // the value is recieved properly
$currentCategoryId = $currentCategory[0]->term_id; // the value is assigned properly

$categories = get_categories('hide_empty=0'); // the value is recieved properly
$optionname = "postcats"; // the value is recieved properly
$emptyvalue = "";

// SELECET DROP DOWN TERMS
echo '<select name="'.$optionname.'" class="clientList"><option selected="'.$selected.'" value="'.$emptyvalue.'">'.__('Choose a category','sagive').'</option>';
foreach($categories as $category){

    // HERE I ENTERED AN ELSE THAT WOULD CLEAN
    // THE VALUE OF $SELECTED

    if($currentCategoryId == $category->term_id) {$selected = 'selected="selected"';} else {$selected = ''}
    echo '<option name="'.$category->term_id.'" value="'.$category->term_id.'" '.$selected.'>'.$category->name.'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
?>
```